# asp.net login - how to inturrupt with a message prompt?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, login-control

I have seemingly easy problem and am having trouble designing the right solution.

I have a normal asp .net login control. When the user logs in (and is successfully authenticated) I want to display a JavaScript message prompt like:

> Warning: This is a government system...etc

There are a million and one ways to do this... but I really wanted to keep it inside my login user control. I played around with the following methods with no luck:

```
protected void OnAuthenticate(object sender, AuthenticateEventArgs e)
{
    Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "warning", "alert('hello');", true);
}

protected void OnLoggingIn(object sender, LoginCancelEventArgs e)
{
    Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "warning", "alert('hello');", true); 
}

protected void OnLoggedIn(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "warning", "alert('hello');", true);
}
```

It seems like the postback page lifecycle is screwing me over.

Maybe I should think about this differently?

> login page -> (success) -> warning message page -> user dashboard page

Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

-Josh

EDIT: I've also tried Page.ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptBlock("....");

Comment: Are you redirecting the user after they login with a call to `Response.Redirect()`? This would cause any registered JavaScript not to be emitted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you using a master page/base page and session?  you can do it this way so that the warning would be shown on the first non login page:

```
protected void Page_load(object sender, EventArgs e) 
{
   if (Request.IsAuthenticated && !Page.IsPostBack())     
      if (session["warningShown"] == null or session["warningShown"] == false)
      {
         session["warningShown"] = true;
         Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "warning", "alert('hello');", true); 

      }
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If it helps I used to do something like this with classic ASP back in the day...

My Javascript was along the lines of :

```
if (confirm('Yes or no'))
  {
    return true;
  }
```

This was written to the page with a Response.write statement. If the user clicked OK they would get redirected; if they clicked cancel they'd stay on the page. (I admit it's been a while since I've done this, so this may not be the exact syntax)

This may not be exactly what you're looking for, but it may get you headed in the right direction.